# How does magnetical energy comes in superconducting phase transition

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

Show me this is not a perpetual motion machine.

- Step 1. Put a superconducting material in a strong magnetic field.
- Step 2. Cool down the superconducting material
- Step 3. It levitates
- Step 4. Heat up the superconducting material
- Step 5. It falls
- Step 6. Repeat.

Question: At which step do we pay for the magnetical potential energy?

Comment: Steps where energy transfers occur, i.e. steps 2, 4. Perhaps also step 1, if the material is diamagnetic.